Proper use of @SpringBootTest
I have an application where there are a lot of beans, but there is nowhere without tests, and so I would like to ask how to use the @SpringBootTest annotation correctly? I'm asking this because I'm afraid that if there are a lot of tests that use this annotation, it will be very resource-intensive.
I have already tested individual beans, for example, using the @DataJpaTest and @Testcontainers annotations
Repeat the question: I would like to ask how to use the @SpringBootTest annotation correctly?
I want my application to deploy efficiently and be covered by tests.
